# application shutdown issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

in a prism application i have created a login form that start in a module. After the user is authenticated the login form wait for all application modules had been initialized (like a splah screen shows some information about the modules loaded), then starts the shell. All seems to work fine except when the user click on the cancel button of the login form. I would like that the application shutdown, but because the login form start in another thread i'm not able to use the Application.Current.Shutdown() (only work Enviroment.Exit(0) but i'm not sure this is a correct way). I try to invoke from Application.Current.Dispatcher but the application still run. 
This is the login module initialization and where i catch the event that should do the application shutdown:

```
public void Initialize()
{        
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (Action) (() =>
        {
            Shell.Show();

            EventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginStatusEvent>().Publish(new LoginStatusEvent { LoginStatus = LoginViewStatus.Close });
        }));      

  ThreadStart showSplash =
    () =>
      {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
          (Action) (() =>
                {
                    Container.RegisterType<LoginViewModel, LoginViewModel>();
                    Container.RegisterType<LoginView, LoginView>();

                    var login = Container.Resolve<LoginView>();

                    EventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginStatusEvent>().Subscribe(e => login.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        (Action)(() =>
                            {
                                if (e.LoginStatus == LoginViewStatus.Aborted)
                                {
                                    login.Close();

                                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Application.Current.Shutdown()));

                                    //Environment.Exit(0);
                                }
                                else if (e.LoginStatus == LoginViewStatus.Close)
                                {
                                    login.Close();                                          
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    WaitForCreation.Set();
                                }
                            })));

                    login.Show();                            
                }));

        Dispatcher.Run();
      };

  WaitForCreation = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  var thread = new Thread(showSplash) {Name = "LoginView Thread", IsBackground = true};
  thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  thread.Start();

  WaitForCreation.WaitOne();
}
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why is your login UI running on the background thread? It seems the login UI should run on the GUI thread. Then you have a BackgroundWorker object (much easier to use than your code above and much more maintainable) that can run ProgressChanged anytime it needs to update the UI as the ProgressChanged method calls back to the GUI thread?

I often overload BackgroundWorker to be something like MyDataObjectBackgroundWorker, and I create a property that holds my object. This way I can pass data easily back and forth with ProgressChanged (like the information on your modules being loaded).